# Why Cisco VPN client window not showing up on screen?

Tags: cisco-vpn-client

I am using Cisco VPN client 5.0.07* version. It was working all right till yesterday & suddenly its client screen stopped showing up on screen. But when I press enter it opens up connection window as I had already configured connection details.

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me while using multiple display monitors with different arrangement( second screen on left & then another on right ). Follow steps to move window back on screen.

```
Switch to Cisco window using alt + tab
Now press alt + space bar
Press M key, which is move option
Now press right/left arrow key
Move mouse pointer.
```

& your Cisco window should start to show up.